# My (valid?) regex doesn't work in gorilla/mux

Tags: regex, go, gorilla

I have this regex in my code:

```
get.HandleFunc("/my/api/user/{userID:^([1-9][0-9]*)$}", app.Handle("user"))
```

But when I run the tests, only 404s are returned. I also tried this:

```
get.HandleFunc("/my/api/user/{userID:\\A([1-9][0-9]*)\\z}", app.Handle("user"))
```

It worked perfectly with my older (but incorrect) regex:

```
get.HandleFunc("/my/api/user/{userID:[0-9]{1,}}", app.Handle("user"))
```

I wonder what is wrong with my new regex. I tried to test it on some websites and also by using the `regexp` package in Go, and it always worked. As far as I know, `gorilla/mux` uses Go's `regexp` package. Any idea?

What I want is to detect positive integers excluding zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**anchors**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html) are most likely the issue here, you're trying to assert at start/end of string positions.

I would simply try modifying the older (working) regular expression as follows:

```
get.HandleFunc("/my/api/user/{userID:[1-9][0-9]*}", app.Handle("user"))
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. In mux's source code I found `pattern.WriteByte('^')` and `pattern.WriteByte('$')`. So these are probably added by default.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect positive integers excluding 0, you should use this characters class: `[1-9]\d*`

That means, the first digit must be between 1 and 9. The other digits (if present, look at the `*`) can be any integer, 0 included.